# Python Selenium get value from certain class and get inside element

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get the information in value=" " from this code. As long as the class has the word orange in it, I want to store the value.

Expected result in this case is storing value "3781" in a variable.

what I tried so far

```
def getToTickets(self):
        tickets = self.browser.find_elements_by_class_name("tc-row")
        for ticket in tickets:
            ticketID = ticket.find_element_by_class_name("d_w").get_attribute("value")
            print(ticketID)
```

[image]

P.S: If I double click on the value I want I get this:
[image]

Edit:

Tried this one

```
def getToTickets(self):
    self.browser.get("https://support.cts.ae/WOListView.do")
    tickets = self.browser.find_elements_by_class_name("tc-row")
    for ticket in tickets:
        ticketID = ticket.find_element_by_id("RequestsView_r_0_5")
        ticketID = ticket.find_element_by_class_name("d_w").get_attribute('innerHTML')
        print(ticketID)
        break
```

Result was

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="3781" templateid="4">&nbsp;
```

Tried this one:

```
def getToTickets(self):
    self.browser.get("https://support.cts.ae/WOListView.do")
    tickets = self.browser.find_elements_by_class_name("tc-row")
    for ticket in tickets:
        ticketID = ticket.find_element_by_id("RequestsView_r_0_5")
        ticketID = ticket.find_element_by_class_name("d_w").get_attribute("value")
        print(ticketID)
        break
```

Got this result :

```
None
```

Comment: Why not simply put `.text` on it ? `ticketID = ticket.find_element_by_class_name("d_w").text`

Comment: I get a blank Result / Check my edit

Comment: You're getting close... you want "innerHTML" here...  in your last one use ticketID.find_element...  (you'll be in scope of the TD element.  Or use an XPATH of something like "//td[contains(@id, "RequestsView_r_0_5)]/div" to get the DIV... then element..get_attribute('innerHTML')